# Create graphic style out of attributes illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, graphic-styles

I am wanting to make a graphic style that I can apply to text.
The image below is type that has been turned into outlines. I had to turn it into outlines so the stroke would be around the outside.

Basically I have a bunch of titles that need to have these same attributes applied. What I've done is..

> created text outline

> added stroke

> transformed and offset to create the depth for black

> Tilted on an angle

Then I expanded everything.

Not sure if its possible with Graphic Styles to save objects that have been transformed a specific way as a style or is it merely to add colour, strokes and effects etc?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you can create something using the **Appearance Panel**, it can be saved as a Graphic Style.

**All** of those settings can be accomplished using *live text* and and then saved as a graphic style to apply to different (live) text. There's no need to outline anything.

[image]

You could also probably use `Effect > Warp > Rise` rather than the free Distort. You might find controlling the warp easier.

[image]

Saved as a **Graphic Style**....

[image]